# best data structer for such a cross html table build

Tags: php, html

There are some groups which holds some data for example empty cars, reservated cars and cars which will return.. So if user want to see a cross table between car groups and dates,
I want to create a cross html table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                        <th>Date1</th>
                        <th>Date2</th>
                        <th>Date3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!--Group1-->
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4">Group1</td>
                        <td>Empty</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>3</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>On the Res</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>6</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Will Return</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Remains</td>
                        <td>-11</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>-9</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--Group1 Ends -->

                    <!--Group1-->
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4">Group2</td>
                        <td>Empty</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>3</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>On the Res</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>6</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Will Return</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Remains</td>
                        <td>-11</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>-9</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--Group1 Ends -->



                </table>
```

And here is the output of this html code:

[image]

What is the best php array structure for this kind cross table?

Thanks.

Comment: As i mentioned, i am looking for array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bound to get a variety of opinions.  For what it's worth, this is one possible structure that would make sense and would be fairly straightforward to code against.

The "groups" could be the top-level keys, and the value for each group would be an array of arrays:

```
$table_data = [
    'Group1' => [
        [ 'Title' => 'Empty',
          'Date1' => 5,
          'Date2' => 12,
          'Date3' => 3
        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'On the Res',
          'Date1' => 8,
          'Date2' => 6,
          'Date3' => 6
        ],
        // etc...
    ],
    'Group2' => [
        [ 'Title' => 'Empty',
          'Date1' => 5,
          'Date2' => 12,
          'Date3' => 3
        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'On the Res',
          'Date1' => 8,
          'Date2' => 6,
          'Date3' => 6
        ],
        // etc...
    ],
    // etc...
];
```

My thoughts on the PHP loop would be something like so:

```
foreach( $table_data AS $group => $rows ) {
    $rowspan = count( $rows );
    echo '<tr><td rowspan="' . $rowspan . '">' . $group . '</td>';
    $tr = '';
    foreach( $rows AS $row ) {
        echo $tr . '<td>' . implode( '</td><td>', array_values( $row ) ) . '</td></tr>';
        $tr = '<tr>';
    }
}
```